# \vspace*{\fill} exceeds a page in multicols* environment

Tags: minipage, multicol, zref

I am using TexLive 2017, and would like to record positions of objects. But the bottom of the last `\vspace*{\fill}` usually exceeds a page when it is inside `multicols*` environment. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}

\usepackage[%
includeheadfoot, headheight=15pt, headsep=14pt, footskip=25pt,
top=8mm, bottom=8mm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}

\newwrite\writer
\openout\writer=\jobname.coors\relax

\begin{multicols*}{2}

\noindent%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \zsavepos{tl}\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{demo}\zsavepos{br}
\end{minipage}%
\par%

\zsavepos{vfill-top}\vspace*{\fill}\zsavepos{vfill-bot}\pagebreak[0]

\edef\temp{\zposy{vfill-top} \zposy{vfill-bot}}
\write\writer\expandafter{\temp}

\end{multicols*}

\closeout\writer

\end{document}
```

After compiling twice:

```
$ cat jobname.coors
44648671 -3423457
```

The bottom of `\vspace*{\fill}` is negative, and it means the bottom exceeds the page.

I have made 2 separate experiments:

1. When `\zsavepos{tl}\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{demo}\zsavepos{br}` is replaced by `\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{demo}`, the recorded coordinates are `45435103 3130143`. It looks fine.
2. When `\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}` and `\end{minipage}%` are removed, the recorded coordinates are `45435103 3130143`. It looks also fine.

I have no idea if this is an issue of some package, or I use them incorrectly, and what is the right way to record positions of `\vspace*{\fill}` inside `multicols*`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It is fine here. Coordinates are written to the aux file by zref at the 1st compilation. And at the 2nd compilation, their values can be retrieved by \zposy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a box if you want to record the end position:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}

\usepackage[%
includeheadfoot, headheight=15pt, headsep=14pt, footskip=25pt,
top=8mm, bottom=8mm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}%\today

\begin{multicols*}{2}

\noindent%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \zsavepos{tl}\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{demo}\zsavepos{br}
\end{minipage}%
\par%

\zsavepos{vfill-top}\vspace*{\fill}\mbox{\zsavepos{vfill-bot}}\pagebreak[0]

\edef\temp{\zposy{vfill-top} \zposy{vfill-bot}} \show\temp

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: or even `\hbox` rather than `\mbox` (which avoids starting a paragraph)

Comment: Yes, good y-coordinates got. I want to know further: 1. Why a box is required? 2. Why 2 experiments get good value?

Comment: When you insert a `\zsavepos{tl}` before the graphicx you are changing the height of the minipage to zero and its depth to the height of the image. This changes the way multicols breaks the columns.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried to read multicols code to dig out the root cause, but it is far beyond my TeX knowledge. I think to understand this issue easily, I can assume that all explicit boxes should be placed within a page, and your solution works. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Just to pinch in, I had the same issue recently. The solution for this related issue was to compile the latex a few more times, which should not require the use of \hbox or \mbox. I currently do it 3 times.