# How to shrink the gap between two images with a box between them

Tags: spacing

Due to this issue [\vspace*{\fill} exceeds a page in multicols* environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401381/vspace-fill-exceeds-a-page-in-multicols-environment), a box has to be inserted between adjacent images, and this introduce extra gap between these images.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
    \noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{demo}
    \end{minipage}\par

    \mbox{\zsavepos{pos}}\par

    \noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{demo}
    \end{minipage}\par
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

An obvious gap exists:

[image]

Without `\mbox{\zsavepos{pos}}\par` the gap is small:

[image]

How to shrink the gap?

Comment: Why do you use `\mbox` there at all?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Because of this issue https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401381/vspace-fill-exceeds-a-page-in-multicols-environment and the MWE pattern formed

Comment: why have you got minipages around the images? Unless you have text as well in your real document, they are doing nothing useful.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The MWE is a simplified version. In my real project a minipage contain other stuff. To retain the important structure, I keep minipages here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\mbox{\zsavepos{pos}}\vspace{-\baselineskip}
```

I suppose. Or perhaps

```
\mbox{\zsavepos{pos}}\vspace{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-2\parskip\relax}
```

if you have non-zero parskip.

The `\par`s wouldn't be necessary I think, it's the same as an empty line, and you have those both before and after the `\mbox`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
    \noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{demo}
    \end{minipage}

    \mbox{\zsavepos{pos}}\vspace{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-2\parskip\relax}

    \noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{demo}
    \end{minipage}
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes! This is a good example on negative space, which I have never used before.